# Affecting a class of a particular row onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my page have nested records and each of the nested record has a total number of clicks per each record in a div called `"count"`. I want to add 1 to the total number of each div onclick of the button with a class of `view`. Currently what i'm achieving is onclick on the button view, 1 is added to the all the nested `count divs`, but i want it to affect the particular row on which i click the view button

```
$(document).ready(function(){



$('.view').click(function() {
 counter=parseInt($('.count').html());
            counter++;
            $('.count').html(counter);



        });
    });
```

html

```
 <table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><div>4</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="view">CLICK ME</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>12</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="view">CLICK ME</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a fiddle and ill help

Comment: don't know how to do a fiddle but i'm adding my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without IDs, you can use `parent()` and `prev()` to access the previous row in the table, then drill down to your div with `find()`.

If there are more than one `<div>` in your row, then either

1. Use `find("div").eq(x)` where x is the div index you want starting from 0 ([ref](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)).
2. Give the div a class name like `<div class="count_holder">` and you can then do `find("div.count_holder")`.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.view').on("click", function() {
    $target = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("div").eq(1);
    counter = parseInt($target.html());
    counter++;
    $target.html(counter);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Count:</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="view">CLICK ME</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Count:</div>
      <div>12</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="view">CLICK ME</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when i place the divs in a table it fails to work. why?

Comment: From the HTML you provided, this works. You must have more HTML that we are not seeing in your question. I suggest you update your question with more of your actual, relevant HTML.

Comment: Done. Please see my updated answer. Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nqc1ov61/1/

Comment: is the .eq the class of the div?

Comment: No, it is the index of the all the found divs. Here is the doc: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(.view).on("click", function (e ) {
    var btn = $(e.target);
    var count = btn.prev().html();
    count++;
    btn.prev().html(count);
});
```

No need to parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your counter and button in a div and then try the js code below:

```
   <div class = "parent">
       <div class="count">4</div>
         <button class="view">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "parent">
       <div class="count">12</div>
         <button class="view">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>



    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.view').click(function() {
      var count = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.count');
      counter = count.html();
      counter++;
     count.html(counter);
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvxb1y7b/